# How can I make different HTML and component files in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Is there any way to make two different files for HTML and components in Vue.js? Meaning the HTML code is in a different file from the component's code like with Angular.

Comment: Well you could just import your component code from within the html file, would that solve your issue ?

Comment: That's working fine but I want to make two different files.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal isn't to avoid precompilation, you can still use single-file components and split the js and css into different files. They include an example of this structure in the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html#What-About-Separation-of-Concerns).

```
<template>
  <div>This will be pre-compiled</div>
</template>
<script src="./my-component.js"></script>
<style src="./my-component.css"></style>
```

Comment: Then how can i call this view using route.